# Angular e2e Testacular Test: How To Tell Visibility?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, modal-dialog, karma-runner

**Question**

Has anyone successfully tested if a Bootstrap Modal is displayed when a button is clicked?

**Details**

I am writing a Testacular test that checks to see if a Bootstrap modal is displayed when a button is clicked.  The problem is that the call to `css('display')` returns `'none'` even though I can see that the window pops up and is visible.

I'm wondering if there's something kooky going on with the Bootstrap Modal that duplicates a block of html then displays that with a different id.  I certainly hope not!

**Code**

***The scenario***

```
describe('e2e', function() {

  beforeEach(function() {
    browser().navigateTo('/chessClub/');
  });


  it('should display editor when add member button clicked', function() {
    expect(element('title').text()).toBe("Chess Club");

      expect(element('#myModal').css('display')).toBe('none'); //as expected, it is none
              //click the button to show the modal
      element('#addMemberButton','Add Member Button').click();

              //this 2nd expect still return 'none'
      expect(element('#myModal').css('display')).toBe('block');

  });

});
```

***test output***

```
Chrome 25.0 e2e should display editor when add member button clicked FAILED
    expect element '#myModal' get css 'display' toBe "block"
    /Users/jgordon/learning/chessClub/web-app/test/e2e/scenarios.js:17:4: expected "block" but was "none"
```

***html***

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">{{editorLabel}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
            <label>
                Name
            </label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="editedMember.name" placeholder="John Doe">
            <label>
                Grade
            </label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="editedMember.grade">
            <label>
                Ladder Position
            </label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="editedMember.ladderPosition">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="saveMember()">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up just needing to call `sleep(1)` on the test.  I guess the code that shows the modal wasn't as fast as the test was at checking the style.

Comment: Downvoted: sleep() is never the right thing in a test.

Answer (score 7):

One way, though a bit hacky is to use the `:visible` selector and count how many matches there are

```
expect(element('#someElement:visible').count()).toBe(1);
```

[Source](https://coderwall.com/p/7v0-ca)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do the following to check if the element is hidden:

```
expect(element("#id_element").css("display")).toBe("none");
```

And to check if this element is visible:

```
expect(element("#id_element").css("display")).not().toBe("none");
```

I believe this is not the best way. But it is simple, and it worked for me.

Cheers!